# how to convert a vector of characters to quantitative data

Tags: r

I have a vector with the following data:

```
data<-c('ab','ab','ab','cd','cd','cd','ef','ef')
```

how can I convert that data by using R so that it gets transformed with the following pattern:

```
ab=1
cd=2
ef=3
```

so that the vector will be converted to:

```
data=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `match`

```
match(data, unique(data))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
```

Or in place of `unique(data)`, you can specify the vector of elements to match.

```
match(data, c('ab', 'cd', 'ef'))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's basically what a "factor" is in R. you can do

```
as.numeric(factor(data, levels=c("ab","cd","ef")))
```

You could also use a named lookup vector

```
vv<-c(ab=1, cd=2, ef=3)
vv[data]
# or unname(vv[data]) if the names really bother you
```